# creating new column based on values in other columns with multiple values

Tags: r, dataframe

I want 2 columns that have the first string of the column info1 and the last string of the column info 2.

Here is a view of my data:

```
id             info1                                 info2
1              2012/11/03 22:09:00                      2012/11/03 22:03:00, 2012/12/11 22:09:02  
2              2012/12/13 22:15:00                      2013/6/24 23:30:00
3              2013/8/25 00:38:00, 2013/5/07 01:55:00   2017/4/10 02:08:00, 2012/11/6 00:15:00
```

I want:

```
id          info3                 info4
1          2012/11/03 22:09:00    2012/12/11 22:09:02 
2          2012/12/13 22:15:00    2013/6/24 23:30:00
3          2013/8/25 00:38:00     2012/11/6 00:15:00
```

Can someone help?

Thanks!

Comment: You can use `df1 %>% mutate(info3 = map2(info1, info2, ~ c(first(.x), last(.y))))` or in `base R`, `df1$info3 <- Map(function(x, y) c(x[1], y[length(y)]), df1$info1, df1$info2)`

Comment: Does the original data contain the `*`?

Comment: It is better to clarify whether the columns are list or string

Comment: Thank you, Akrun. Allow me to clarify. First, I realized that I actually need two columns, one that has the first value of the first column and another that has the last value of the second column. The values are actually characters. I have added in an "a" to indicate this. And no, the * is not in the data, I used that to emphasize what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `stri_extract_first_regex` and `stri_extract_last_regex` from `stringi`.

```
library(stringi)
library(dplyr)

df3 %>%
  mutate(info3 = stri_extract_first_regex(info1, '\\d+/\\d+/\\d+ \\d+:\\d+:\\d+'), 
         info4 = stri_extract_last_regex(info2, '\\d+/\\d+/\\d+ \\d+:\\d+:\\d+')) %>%
  select(-info1, -info2)

#  ID               info3               info4
#1  1 2015/10/22 00:28:00 2015/10/23 08:18:00
#2  2  2016/5/30 22:10:00  2016/6/02 05:45:00
#3  3                <NA>                <NA>
#4  4  2016/9/19 00:10:00  2016/9/20 08:29:30
#5  5                <NA>                <NA>
```

Comment: Thank you, Ronak!!! That didn't completely work for me; however, your code did inspire me to use paste. Here is what I did.                                              
rest_interval_exclusion$try <- paste(df$info1, df1$info2, sep = ",")  
%>% extract(c("info3", "info4"), regex = '(.*?),.*,(.*)').  I'm getting an error message with the extract though. Is there something blatantly off that I did? Thank you in advance!!!

Comment: @D.Fowler Can you add your data using `dput(head(data))` ?

Comment: I just added it above. There are a lot of dates and times, so I'm not sure how interpretable the data are. Let me know if it's not clear....and thank you!!!

Comment: No the syntax which you have used is wrong. Why are you not using `unite` as in my answer? I

Comment: It does not work when there is only 1 string in each column (like in ID2). There's just blanks.

Comment: So when there is only 1 string you want to copy it in both the columns?

Comment: Yes, in addition to copying the first and last of multiple strings when there is that is in a row. Like what I have above. Thank you for your patience and willingness to help.

Comment: @D.Fowler See updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an approach from the Tidyverse:

We can use regular expressions to extract non-comma characters followed by a comma from `info1` and characters preceded by a comma and a space from `info2`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
data %>% 
  mutate(info3 = str_extract(info1,"^[^,]+(?=,)"),
         info4 = str_extract(info2,"(?<=, )[^,]+$"))
  id                                                         info1                                    info2               info3               info4
1  1                      2015/10/22 00:28:00, 2015/10/23 00:09:00 2015/10/22 07:20:00, 2015/10/23 08:18:00 2015/10/22 00:28:00 2015/10/23 08:18:00
2  2 2015/10/22 00:28:00, 2015/10/24 00:01:00, 2015/10/23 00:09:00 2015/10/22 07:20:00, 2015/10/23 08:18:00 2015/10/22 00:28:00 2015/10/23 08:18:00
```

**Sample Data**

```
data <- structure(list(id = 1L, info1 = "2015/10/22 00:28:00, 2015/10/23 00:09:00", 
    info2 = "2015/10/22 07:20:00, 2015/10/23 08:18:00"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -1L))
```

Comment: Hi Ian. Thank you for your response. I realized that my data description was not accurate and that I actually need 2 columns, one with the first value from the first column and another with the last value from the second column. My data not numeric but in fact characters.

Comment: Ian, apologies again for being unclear. I was trying to create a very simple example originally with just numbers, but I realize that wasn't the best approach as the code generated really depends on the data. So, I am actually working with data like what is now illustrated above. Is there a way to modify your code to make this work? Again, my apologies for being unclear and any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Thank you, Ian! It does work when there are 2 strings in each column. How would I modify the code if there were three or more strings (as shown in column 2)?